# Inject bundle configuration into twig without globals

Tags: symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

I'm working with Symfony 3.4 - I have a UserBundle which extends the FOSUserBundle. This bundle will be used in several projects and I want to create a configuration for my bundle. For example, to enable or disable the registration link in the login form.

I just created a configuration to do that - but the configuration variables are not injected into the twig templates. The Symfony docs says, I have to define it as global parameters - but that is not a nice way, because I don't want to set these params in each project.

The bundle configuration:

```
public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
{
    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('user');

    $rootNode
        ->children()
            ->booleanNode('loginform_registration_link')->isRequired()->end()
        ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
}
```

Here is the code how I load the configuration:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');

    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $container->setParameter('user.loginform_registration_link', $config['loginform_registration_link']);
}
```

The question is: How can I inject the configuration parameters into twig without setting it as global twig variables, without touching the project configuration again and without overriding each action/controller of FOSUserBundle?

Comment: It's not possible to extend config.yml from bundle and set the twig globals there? So you don't do that in every project? I think it's the way to go.

Comment: If you really think you need to do this then take a look at how the TwigBundle/DependencyInjection injects it's globals.  But a twig extension is probably a simpler and cleaner approach.